# Google reCaptcha v.2 causes cross-site cookie warnings in Chrome browser

Tags: cookies, recaptcha

I added a google reCaptcha script v2 to the login page of my app. It works alright but I get the following console warnings every time it initializes:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/
>   was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome
>   will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set
>   with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer
>   tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032

Seems like this reCapthca iframe is saving cookies but doing it the wrong way. Is anybody facing the same problem? Is there any way to affect this behavior and get rid of these console warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is related to this one: [SameSite warning Chrome 77](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58270663/7919626)

Basically, it will be the libraries job to fix their cookies and the warning serves only has a warning.

Comment: It is not just a warning.  It's blocking for me.