# Cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute .NET

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

How to solve `SameSite` attribute?

:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

same for google.com, linkedin, facebook.com, twitter.com. etc

Unable to add 'Samesite' attributes. What will be the best way to get this solve?

Comment: you need to disable cors policy as a workaround

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SameSite warning Chrome 77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270663/samesite-warning-chrome-77)

Answer (score -1):

The reason why you are getting this warning is because you are using an external resource (like an image). In my case, I copied an image URL/Address online and included it into my project. I didn't save it in a folder, so I got that warning.

The way I solved it is simple: I just said it: download whatever file you are trying to access locally and that warning will disappear.

Hope this helps

Comment: What if we don't want to store these files locally ? Let's say I have 12K of these files ?