# socket.io sets cross-site cookie without same-site attribute

Tags: npm, socket.io

I have a socket.io application and recently I got this warning:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at *URL* was set
>   without the `SameSite` attribute. 
>       A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.
>
> You can review cookies in developer tools under
>   Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.`

Apparently it is something that Chrome will be updating in the future:
[SameSite warning Chrome 77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270663/samesite-warning-chrome-77)

I already tried [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2276) but to no apparent avail : `io = io.listen(server, { cookie: false });`

I think the cookie doesn't do anything, so how can I disable io from setting it?

Comment: some issue for me. Did you solve?

Comment: No, since the update is planned somewhere Q2 of 2020 I haven't given it much thought since I posted here.

Answer (score 5):

As per the issue reported in Socket IOs' github repo, that cookie is not used for anything; you can disable it by setting `cookie: false` in the server options.

But what you have missed is setting `{cookie: false}` option when initializing the socket, not `http.listen`. The solution provided below worked for me that uses express as the server.

```
var server = require('http').createServer(express());
var io = require('socket.io')(server, { path:"/some/path", cookie: false });
```

Comment: This isn't true. The cookie is sometimes used to provide ELB (e.g. haproxy) stickiness when several parallel socket.io servers are available.