# Having issue with chrome warning about socket.io and cross-site request by SameSite attribute

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to fix the warning described in the title. I was getting 2 warnings concerning the same "name and Domain & Path".I updated my code described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485508/2272090) to include `{cookie: false}`. That removed  the warning about "weather a cookie is intended to be set..." but left the other. Any ideas?

[image]

Expanded Affected Resources
[image]

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557911/socket-io-sets-cross-site-cookie-without-same-site-attribute ?

Comment: That link is where I added the {cookie: false} and fixed one of the warnings.

Comment: You should expand the "Affected resources" section to see which cookie is causing the issue.

Comment: @rowan_m I edited my post to include the Affected resources.