# getting error in chrome extension : A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://*******.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i am new here in chrome extension, this is my first chrome extension ever, i have create one crome extension,  when i click on icon of my extesion i am getting error, `A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://*****.com/ was set without the`SameSite`attribute.`, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? here i have mention all the extension files, can anyone please look in to that and help me to resolve this issue ?

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Next",
    "version": "0.1",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "logo.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Hi"
    }
}
```

background.js

```
var i = 1;

function updateIcon() {
    i = 1;
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: ''
    });
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup: "popup.html"
    });
}


chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
    color: [200, 0, 0, 100]
});
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <p><iframe width="500" height="500" src="https://****.com" ></iframe></p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an extension specific problem. The script you load in the popup is responsible for a request that gives you the warning. If it's not under your control then there is not much you can do, the server has to be reconfigured that the script is accessing. Read this for more: [SameSite warning Chrome 77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270663/samesite-warning-chrome-77)