# How to handle third-party cookies in my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have a very simple website which it is just CSS and HTML with no special backend or any database attached to it. it is very simple but there is a box which there is showing a YouTube video on it. I found that there is some errors in this websites console. One is that

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://youtube.com/
> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome
> will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set
> with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer
> tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at...

I searched a lot and then I found that I should handle third-party cookies in my website. but I really do not know how to do it and where I should start. I do not know what is better for my website.

Comment: How about this? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270663/samesite-warning-chrome-77

Comment: Not sure, but a simple fix might be to change `http://youtube.com/` to `https://youtube.com/` note the `s` in `https`..

Comment: @Keith Thank you but it confronts another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, presumably, do not work for YouTube, therefore you cannot change the HTTP responses that YouTube send to people to add the `SameSite` attribute.

This is YouTube's problem and you can't do anything about it.