# Google Chrome v80 'sameSite' parameter issue

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-chrome, samesite

Recently my Google chrome got update which is causing issue in my application . 
My application is using **springboot-1.5** in backend  and **angular 4** in frontend ans also
I am using 
**Google Chrome version -   80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)** 
**OS version -  Windows 10 OS Version 1809 (Build 17763.1098)**

the issue is my rest API calls are failing. As i did some investigation and found that 'sameSite' parameter is newly added in cookies if it is enable then create issue. For the fix, i set sameSite=none for JSESSIONID  in response

```
 response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+cookie.get().getValue()+"; HttpOnly; SameSite=none");
```

and i also tried to update header like below

```
 response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, String.format("%s; %s ; %s", header,"Secure", "SameSite=none"));
```

This fix is working in some machine but not in all the machine. all the machines are having updated chrome ( version 80) 
Please suggest me what actually i should do to fix this issue

Comment: I have recently faced similar kind of issue. My application didn't worked in chrome and it was running in secure protocol (https). When i change the certificate which i used for securing my application from the format of .cer to .pfx, it worked. Just check on this and let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SameSite warning Chrome 77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270663/samesite-warning-chrome-77)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The problem was, im my case some of requests are authenticate but some of them are not. for that i am using multiple security filters and in one of filterer response's cookie was reset as default.