# How to solve Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am a beginner and I am learning react js. In my project, I am using firebase. I have created a sign-in button but can't sign in with google.

I am getting this error:

```
Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Invalid headers set for cookie would be my guess, look into that more.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/security-in-gatsby/

Answer (score 0):

set the header line in your server page (if in PHP) as below:

```
header("Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=whatever; SameSite=None; Secure");
```

Credits : https://pretagteam.com/question/indicate-whether-to-send-a-cookie-in-a-crosssite-request-by-specifying-its-samesite-attribute

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't interfere with the sign-in functionality because firebase handles most of the work internally within its services, with the functions returning only the necessary data object, For example [signInWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#signinwithemailandpassword) returns Promise.

The warning you are getting has to do with the cookies sent by the server-side and not your front end up: Check out a similar issue and a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209313/how-to-specify-samesite-and-secure-on-cookies-using-axios-react-node-express) . Therefore the issue can be resolved by firebase including the `SameSite` attribute in the cookie when sending response, not anything on your client-side.