# QtWebengine Cookie SameSite=None warning

Tags: qt, qml, qtwebengine, webengine

I keep receiving the following warning on `QtWebEngine` calls in QML. How do I resolve this?

```
js: A cookie associated with a resource at <URL> was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`.
```

This thread here [SameSite warning Chrome 77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270663/samesite-warning-chrome-77) says that a cookie header (`HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict`) needs to be set. How do I do it in WebEngineView.

Here is my QML snippet

```
WebEngineView {
    id:primaryVideo

    URL:"http://www.youtube.com/embed/9ldOuVuas1c"
    width:500
    height:250
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN SameSite Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) Dokumentation the SameSite header is part of the response not the request. So it is the responsibility of the server to specify the header correctly

Comment: Ok. But I am fetching my url from youtube. How do i do it then

Comment: I don‘t think you can fix this issue. In the section Fixing Common Warnings (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#Fixing_common_warnings) you can find the exact same issue with the following text: „The warning appears because any cookie that requests SameSite=None but is not marked Secure will be rejected.“